# OS X Homebrew's PHP extensions location

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, php-extension

I Just installed **homebrew/homebrew-php** package, and noticed that extensions dir is actually empty, moreover, all extension directives in php.ini are commented. Despite that, phpinfo shows that all standard extensions (mysql, curl, zlib, etc.) are installed and work.

So, help me to understand, how do those extensions work without extension files and appropriate records in php.ini? How can I turn off some of standard extensions, or replace them by ones from PECL (if I need a different versions or so).

Comment: You may have multiple copies of PHP, so first check that you're running the one you expect, and with an extension directory of where you expect it to be.  Next, I'm not entirely sure but I think it's possible to build PHP with those extensions compiled into the main binary.

Comment: @Brad yeah, I checked that and compared php.ini and extension_dir locations with those are shown in phpinfo. So yea, you're probably right about extensions compiled in bniary, I was thinking about that too. But the question is still open: can I replace or turn off some of them?

Comment: Use which command to understand which binary is running. Use brew info <package > to see relevant information about that package.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to an old question to avoid confusion: As of Apr 2018, Homebrew no longer supports PHP extensions, only a minimum is included with PHP. Use PECL to manage PHP extensions.